# How to keep and delete another part within a cell in Google sheet?

Tags: excel, formula, google-sheets-api

I have a CSV file where in multiple cells I have the following format (Google sheet):

Example cell 1: "9/22/2016 1:41:00" 
OR
Example cell 2: "12/22/2016 1:42:00"

**I want to get rid of everything after the date so "1:41:00".**

I tried various functions such as:
 =LEFT(M2,"10") but the issue is that sometimes there are "9" so i have the first number of the time.
OR
=LEFT(M2, find(" ", M2 & " ") - 8) but I have the same issue as described above
OR 
Split but there is no delimiter

Anyone would know how to keep the date and delete the other half?

Thanks

Comment: are the dates real dates or text that look like dates?

Comment: It is from a CSV file. Currently, they are as text in google sheet

Comment: `=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1& " ")-1)`

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried this one. For reasons I ignore, i need to add "8" at the end to just get the date. Then the issue is that some dates are longer than other (+/- 1 character) so it does not solve the initial issue

Comment: Try `=INT(A1)` just in case it is a true date.

Comment: Thks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

=INDEX(SPLIT(N2," "),0,1) works for me